# how to arrange a SQL table for social website?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, social-networking

I want to make a website that users could post something and their friends could see the post. how do I arrange the table? I have an idea,but does it a good way?:

```
USERS TABLE
-------------
user id| user name| birth day|...

USERS_POST TABLE
-------------
user id|post 1|date|post 2|date|post 3|date......post 9999999|date
```

there is a lot of columns in the USERS_POST TABLE. does there is diffrent way?

Comment: Using a post_id would allow you to use only one post column. You can then join the users and users_post table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need to create a column for every post of a user. 
You will have a post table and a user table.

The post table will for example contain
ID, User ID, Date and a post

For every post you will create a new entry in your post table.

You can now join the user table with the post table to get all the entries.
[image]

EDIT: 
You could ofcourse, not include the userid in the post table, but also create a table to show the relationship between the post and the usertable:

[image]

Comment: you say to throw the posts to the POSTS table and then to find them. but if there is big website ,with a lot of posts doenst it would take a lot of time to get the posts for each user?

Comment: it will be faster - otherwise you would have to create a table with thousands of columns with the value null - plus you would limit yourself to a specific amount of posts.

Comment: as i see it it would take O(n) to go throw all the posts, and if there is a 1B posts it would a minute to find them(lets say that each second it go throw 10 million posts)

Answer (score 0):

With the diferent posts as columns, you'll have to modify the table structure all the time.

What I would to is to create 3 tables:

```
USERS TABLE
-------------
user id| user name| birth day|...

USERS_POSTS TABLE
-------------
user id| post id

POSTS TABLE
-------------
post id| date| post title| post text| ...
```

Then, to get the posts a user has:
    SELECT postid FROM USERS_POSTS WHERE userid=?

And to get the text/title/etc. of any post:
    SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE postid=?

You could also have the post title and text in the USERS_POSTS table, but it won't be as flexible and scalable in the long term.